Please explain samba smbd "No path in service shares"
I am having a problem with samba on my Ubuntu 24.04 server clean install.
Internet connection is working fine, and most of the services I wanted are up and running. These include Lyrion Music Server and ssh. But I cannot access folders I want to make shareable or even get the host to show up in File Explorer, on either of two Windows machines (a desktop running Win 10 connected by Ethernet and a laptop running Win 11 connected by Wi-Fi).
Running testparm produces:
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf  
**WARNING: No path in service shares - making it unavailable!  
NOTE: Service shares is flagged unavailable.**  
Loaded services file OK.  

Note the WARNING text. I do not understand why the paths to the various shares I have listed in the smb.conf file are "unavailable"! (They work perfectly well on the Unix side: I am assuming I can use symbolic links in the paths?). Is it a permissions thing? I have made all of the top level folders in each path wide open, generally using 775, and they are all owned by root:root.
I am able to force Windows File Explorer to find the Ubuntu server ("HostName") by entering the machine name (or the static IP address) in the search bar as \\HostName.local (though I am not convinced the .local is necessary). Windows throws up a prompt for me to enter my login credentials. When I do this I get a message dialog box which reports:
\\\\HostName is not accessible. You might not have permission to use
this network resource.... blah blah blah  

which (I guess) is a consequence of the condition which produces the warning message issued by testparm.
Of course I have granted permission to myself. Or have I? When I run sudo systemctl status smbd it appears that smbd is running fine, but my bold text shows there is a problem:
smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-12-29 16:40:53 PST; 20min ago Docs: man:smbd(8)
man:samba(7)
man:smb.conf(5)
Process: 108179 ExecCondition=/usr/share/samba/is-configured smb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 108182 (smbd)
Status: "smbd: ready to serve connections..."
Tasks: 4 (limit: 14253)
Memory: 15.0M (peak: 37.6M)
CPU: 1.025s
CGroup: /system.slice/smbd.service
├─108182 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
├─108185 "smbd: notifyd" .
├─108186 "smbd: cleanupd "
└─151954 "smbd: client [fe80::a887:d154:c2b4:423e%enp9s0]"

Dec 29 16:40:53 systemd[1]: Starting smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon...
Dec 29 16:40:53 (smbd)[108182]: **smbd.service: Referenced but unset environment variable evaluates to an empty string: SMBDOPTIONS**
Dec 29 16:40:53 systemd[1]: Started smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon.
Dec 29 16:49:43 smbd[151954]: pam_unix(samba:session): session opened for user norman(uid=1000) by (uid=0)

What is the unset environment variable? Where is it located, and what do I need to do to set SMBDOPTIONS?
I have googled numerous sets of instructions both written and on YouTube, and tried quite a few suggestions but with little success. (There are quite a few somewhat similar reports going back over 20 years -- but few of them are resolved.)
I just reviewed a suggestion which mentions the need for a samba user password using sudo smbpasswd -a Usernamehere
I had already set up a password both for myself and for a generic smbuser.
I do not recall having this much trouble when I first set up Samba a few years ago (probably in Ubuntu 20 or 21). I am sure there is something obvious that I have just never paid any attention to before. I am hoping someone can see this as a simple fix.

@user68186 OK., Short irrelevant stories have been deleted.

I don't see in your post what steps you have taken to mount the shares, the mount points and whether this is being done using an /etc/fstab entry and what that complrises

You have in smb.conf a share definition labeled [shares]. It has no path statement path = ... in it. Samba doesn't know what it is you want to share.

@Morbius1 THANK YOU! That is correct and the reason was that I had commented out the entire stanza labeled [Shares]! Doh! I have commented it back in and suddenly things are happening. The reason for my madness is that I had watched a YT vid where I gained the impression the label "Shares" was optional --- and could be replaced by anything. So I had individual paths specified under separate definitions: [Music], [Backups] etc,, each with their own paths.

@graham Good questions thank you. I can provide /etc/fstab and /etc/samba/smb.conf if needed. The mount point is spec'd in fstab for a single RAID array in the form:
UUID=xyz /mnt/RAID ext4 defaults 0 0
I had tried using links to the specific folders in the paths in each definition stanza but replaced them with the fully defined paths last night. That did not appear to make any difference (hence my question about using symbolic links).

So it is beginning to look like things are working. But systemctl status smbd is still producing a warning message (yellow, almost unreadable text):
unset environment variable evaluates to an empty string: SMBDOPTIONS
-- What is the significance of this?
